# Is Trello going to a pay model?

Tags: trello

I'm loving Trello. I love the simplicity of it and how easy it is to build projects in it. I'm creating boards like crazy but I need to know that I'm not setting myself up for a heartache in the next few weeks/months when trello converts over to a pay model, I can't afford. Is trello converting to a pay model? I don't see anywhere that it costs anything. It's amazing and I want to keep using it.

Answer (score 44):

Please see http://trello.com/privacy

> #### Free... for how long?
>
> Trello is free forever. We may add pay-only features in the future, but everything that's free today will be free tomorrow and forever. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Trello has added 'Trello Business class' for business customers.

From the blog article [located here](http://blog.trello.com/introducing-business-class/):

> What’s in the box? All the power of a Trello organization plus extra
>   features like Google Apps integration, extra administrative controls
>   for boards and members, one-click bulk data export, and a new,
>   view-only observer role. All for $25 per month or $200 per year per
>   organization. It doesn’t matter if you’ve got 5 members or 50, 10
>   boards or 200. It’s a simple and affordable price.